# Will this schematic work for my custom LifePo4 BMS and power MOSFET control?

Tags: pcb-design, raspberry-pi, multiplexer, mosfet-driver, solar-charge-controller

I have designed the following schematic which I plan on using as a raspberry pi hat to monitor the individual lifepo4 battery cells wired in series (16s - 48v) and to toggle on or off 2 different power MOSFETs that sit between my solar panel arrays and my solar charge controllers which will allow me to prevent any individual cell from getting overcharged

[image]

Please be patient with me if I have done anything strange or have mixed up the terms or anything in this question and/or in the schematic, I'm far from an electrical engineer (hence why I'm reaching out for help on this)

### The basic rundown of what everything in the schematic does:

- #### The main connector:

B0-0 thru B0-7 and B1-0 thru B1-7 all go to the positive lead on each of the individual battery cells. A1, and A2 will be available for me to be able to use the ADC for in the future if I want to measure the voltage of anything (most likely some shunts) the GPIO pins are also reserved for future use (firing relays, being able to use a temperature sensor possibly, etc)

It's important to note for this that from B1-7 to ground the circuit will provide full voltage from the batteries as that is the equivalent of the main + and - from the battery banks

- #### The voltage regulators:

both receive the battery banks full voltage (48v) one will output 5v to power everything in the circuit that requires 5v (raspberry pi itself included). The other outputs 10v I use for the "bootstrap MOSFETs" (please verify if I am using the term "bootstrap" correctly)

- #### Bootstrap MOSFETs

2 different mosfets to be able to control 2 of these power mosfets:
https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/IXYS%20PDFs/IXKN75N60C.pdf

the mosfets and their respective part numbers are (from my understanding) logic level and will allow me to be able to control the 10v provided from one of the voltage regulators and provided the needed 10v to fully switch on the power mosfets listed above with 2 different GPIO pins on the raspberry pi

- #### Multiplexers

The 2 8 channel high voltage multiplexers (https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX14752-MAX14753-1515255.pdf) will have each individual battery + lead (from the main connector) connected to one of the channels, the multiplexers will be controlled by the raspberry pi's gpio pins to select which of the 16 cells will get routed to the voltage divider and then to the ADC to be able to loop through and check the voltage of each cell

- #### ADS1115 (analog to digital converter)

I copied the schematic of Spark Fun's ADS1115 IC and integrated it into my PCB to allow for the voltage coming from the voltage divider to be read by the Pi

- #### BM Connector

this will allow me to have a connector to plug in the 2 power MOSFETs and to connect their respective grounds to the - side of the solar panel array (schematic for how the panels will connect to the power MOSFETs and into the charge controller shown below)

I need to make sure I have the functionality of the MOSFETs on the first diagram correct so that they properly operate the MOSFETs for the charge controllers. To the best of my knowledge, the way the MOSFETs are configured is the low logic level MOSFET will be pulled high by default which will put 5V at the BM leads (under the threshold of what turns the power MOSFETs on) so the power MOSFET won't pass any current. When the logic level MOSFET is set to LOW from the GPIO pin on the pi, the pull-up resistor for the BM leads will pull the gate of the power MOSFETs to 10v and therefore will pass the necessary current from the solar panels to the charge controllers

[image]

Right now I'm having to manually monitor the voltage of the cells and manually turn the breakers off for the solar panels once the cells are fully charged which is a huge pain as I'm sure you can imagine. So any help or guidance on getting this to work would be HUGELY appreciated!

Comment: I gather that normally the RPi ensures that only one of the analog muxes is enabled at at time. I would put pull-down resistors on the B1_SEL and B2_SEL lines to make sure they are not selected while the RPi is powering up.

Comment: Excellent point. Just add a 10k resistor from B1_SEL and B2_SEL to GND?

Comment: Yeah - that'll work.